# Illegal option: Files\Android"Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool Key and Certificate Management Tool

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio, apk

I am trying to make apk file of my flutter app but facing problem i searched for this in Stackoverflow but not found any suitable answer which worked for me
i am using windows

```
 C:\"Program Files"\Android\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\SuD\upload-keystore -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

get [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SQXW.jpg)

Comment: ohhh i got this , we have to use  ` C:\\"Program Files"\Android\\"Android Studio"\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\MyPc\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload` double \ where there is space like in "Program Files" and also in \\'Android Studio'

Comment: After this i was trying to "flutter build appbundle" in which i was facing error `a problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > malformed \uxxxx encoding.`  this is solved by using / in key.properties  store File address again i m facing some problem lets see...

Comment: Again i faced problem in app Icon error was `A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade > Android resource compilation failed AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature. ` i searched this but not found any helpful answer at last i make my icon from [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) which work earlier i made png file from [link](https://appicon.co/) which didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\\"Program Files"\\"Android"\\"Android Studio"\\jre\\bin\\keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\pprak\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Please give path command in the above format. Use double \ in all the places where it mentions the Android SDK bin path.

See below images for the solution happened:-

1.) Did not applied double \ at all places. So it gave error.
[image]

2.) Added Double \ at all the places in path. So it did not give error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write your path to keytool in quotes like

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -genkey -v
-keystore "c:\Users\SuD\upload-keystore" -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```